# Multiplying two number arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, digits

Can anyone please tell me how to multiply two number arrays in C? The number arrays are basically derived from two strings containing digits. eg: 123456 and 132465.

Edit: I had two string as `S1 = "123456"` and `S2="132546"`. I then converted these two strings into array of ints i.e. int IS1[6] and IS2[6] so that

```
IS1[1] = 1, IS1[2] = 2......
```

and

```
IS2[1] = 1, IS2[2] = 3.....
```

Now I have to mulitply these two arrrays. Please help.

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: Multiply how? string[0] * string[1]? Or iterate through the array?

Comment: Well if you convert the strings into IS1[1]=1, ... it's too late to use `atoi` then, but the number represented by the array IS1 is IS1[6] + 10 * IS1[5] + 100 * IS1[4] + ...

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what exactly you want to multiply. If you need to multiply two null terminated strings in a `char[]`, you can convert them to `int` values with `atoi`:

```
int result = atoi(str1) * atoi(str2);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the paper-and-pencil arithmetics and don't know how to do that, here is the [illustration](http://www.klever.net/spilikin/arithmetikin/multiply).

Comment: Nice link. Regarding the "pen-and-pencil", one of them has to be able to receive marks from the other.

Comment: Oops, Pascal, fixed this one. But it was funny.

Answer (score 1):

I just code a simple program multiply two number stored in 2 line in file using algorithm long multiplication. It can multiply two number which have more than 1 billion number in each other

**Example:**

```
            23958233
            5830 ×
         ------------
            00000000  ( =      23,958,233 ×     0)
           71874699   ( =      23,958,233 ×    30)
          191665864   ( =      23,958,233 ×   800)
         119791165    ( =      23,958,233 × 5,000)
```

**Source code:**

Please review and give your comment
http://code.google.com/p/juniormultiply/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are small enough, parse them into ints (`atoi`).

If they are too large to fit into ints:

- use a library such as [gmp](http://gmplib.org/)
- or use the pencil-and-paper algorithm, but you'll be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to generate an array containing the multiplications, you could use:

```
int *a, *b, *c; // pointers to arrays of size n
for (unsigned i=0;i<n;++i)
  c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
```

If you want the inner product, this is how you could do it:

```
int *a, *b; // pointers to arrays of size n
int res = 0;
for (unsigned i=0;i<n;++i)
  res += a[i] * b[i];
```

If, like previous answers suggest, what you wanted was to treat the two arrays as numbers you could use the [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function as mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

If it is for a real project, do the conversion.

If this is an exercise of algorithm, do the multiple loop according to the pencil and paper approach.