# How to Multiply Two textfield values Without converting the text into integer or Number

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two text fields and user entered the values. I can get the values of textFields like below

```
NSString *number1 = firstTextField.text;
NSString *number2 = secondTextField.text;
```

I want to multiply `number1` and `number2` without converting them into integer or number.I am doing like below

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*%@",number1,number2]];
NSLog(@"Multiplication result is----%@",[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
```

I don't know if it is correct or not. If it is not correct please give me the suggestions how it can be possible.

Comment: I dont think its possible. I dont think strings have any mathematical operations. 
Whats the issue with converting them, just out of interest?

Comment: what do mean by that?. How will you multiply a string?.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelM, Why can't you just convert them into integers? That certainly seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: Without converting them to numbers, you're asking your program to multiply strings? That's like asking you "What is `Rams x Chowdary`?"

Comment: you can do it by this way NSLog(@"the multiplication is %d",(number1.intValue * number2.intValue));

Comment: @eptdeveloper: question is, without converting or casting strings

Comment: Keep on asking question like this and soon Stackoverflow will award you a badge FUNNY QUESTION :P

Comment: @BishalGhimire: no matter of award by SO.Question is question.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question asked by the interviewer. Do you have the **exact** question?

Comment: @preetam : where he mentioned do not use casting?

Comment: @eptdeveloper: what is diffirence is casting and converting?

Comment: casting means your string will remain still string after some operation but converting means you're converting one object to another object for more you can read apple developer documentations

Comment: @eptdeveloper: k thanks for answer but I dont think interviewer want thins

Comment: @preetam : if you have any better solution or suggestion is most welcome there are lots of knowledge hungry persons like me here.

Comment: Guys i got the solution by using NSExpression it can be possible

Comment: then post your answer and if it is better than @Manuel then accept also

Comment: NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*%@",firstTextField.text,secondTextField.text]];
    NSLog(@"Multiplication Result is----%@",[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);

Comment: @RamsChowdary: its not working

Comment: @preetam For my end its working once check your side

Comment: why dont you post your answer below?

Comment: @preetam this is my own post that's why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using NSExpression is one way to Multiply/Add/Subtract two number strings without converting them into integer or number.

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:expressionFormat];
```

You are using here expressionFormat as `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*%@",number1,number2];`.

If you want to add or subtract number1 and number2 then replace * with + or -. In this way you have to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

If the question was in an interview.
The interviewers were probably expecting you to write a method to go through both arrays and multiply the characters (converting one by one to integers) or (also identifying the represented character to know the equivalent integer number).

Searching on google there are some examples in different languages.

JAVA

http://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/string-multiplication/

[string multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446326/string-multiplication)

C++

[Multiplying two number arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869245/multiplying-two-number-arrays)

It is a common question in interviews.

Answer (score 1):

I simply used textfields... and used the values that the user input into those textfields... here is one calculation example that has worked for me... in this example the user is trying to find the volume of beachstone they would need to order... the formula is pretty straight forward. Make sure you use the math brackets () to distinguish order of operations...

```
-(IBAction)calculate_beachstone:(id)sender {

float floatanswer =

   ([area1.text floatValue])+([area2.text floatValue])+([area3.text floatValue])+([area4.text floatValue])+([area5.text floatValue])+([area6.text floatValue])+([area7.text floatValue])+([area8.text floatValue])+([area9.text floatValue])+([area10.text floatValue]))

  *([beachstone_depth.text floatValue])/12)/27);

NSString *stringRectResult=[[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%.1f",floatanswer];

answer_beachstone.text=stringRectResult;
}
```

I am adding the text found in the textfield (which user can only use numbers for input - custom keyboard)... in this example I have up to 10 fields which can be added together... then I use the * (multiply)  to apply a depth in this example, and convert it back to a text string so I can display the result somewhere else...
In fact, if you write this part **`answer_beachstone`** to NSUserDefaults, you can use the result anywhere in different controllers, by calling it back.

If you're interested, here is how I did that...

```
-(IBAction)save_answer_beachstone:(id)sender {

save_answer_beachstone = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:answer_beachstone.text];
[answer_beachstone setText:save_answer_beachstone];
NSUserDefaults *save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[save setObject:save_answer_beachstone forKey:@"save_answer_beachstone"];
```

}

Then I can use the resulting "answer" in any controller inside viewDidLoad...

```
[answer_beachstone setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save_answer_beachstone"]];
```

I know the question was asked 4 years ago, but this formula syntax works for me in a number of ways, in various apps...

Answer (score -1):

You can't multiply two strings. It's not possible.

For this you have to convert it into `Integer` or int using `NSNumber` or using:

```
[secondTextField.text intValue].

NSInteger number = [firstTextField.text integerValue]*[secondTextField.text integerValue];
```